# Black hole atlases

Tags: black-holes, coordinate-systems, event-horizon, topology, singularities

What sort of [atlases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)) of spaces that contain a black hole (that is, including the space inside the event horizon), if any, are there? Does the central singularity have to be excluded? Are there atlases with a finite number of charts?

Comment: By definition the space inside the event horizon is not available to probe since information may not leave.

Answer (score 3):

An example that covers the whole spacetime with a finite number of charts is [Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates). The only reason you need multiple charts for these coordinates is that the angular coordinates describe a two-sphere, and you can't cover a two-sphere with a single chart.

> Does the central singularity have to be excluded?

In the standard black hole spacetimes, the singularity is not a central point, it's a spacelike surface in the future of every observer. You can see this clearly in the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates. Singularities are not included as part of the manifold, so they don't have coordinates.

Infinitely many atlases are possible. Starting from, say, Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates, you can do any change of coordinates you like, as long as it's well behaved (a diffeomorphism). There are infinitely many such possibilities.

Comment: What about other black hole spacetimes? Can (maximally extended) Kerr be covered by a finite number of charts?